# How to reverse a bitmap color in android with colorfilter?

Tags: android, image, canvas, colors, bitmap

I have a white background image, it is not fit for my app's black background.

I want to make it have black background, or reverse all the colors in the bitmap image.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Get the width and the height of the bitmap. Store the pixels in array, then iterate each pixel, test for white color (hex value) if it is true than swap it with value for black. This is not the best solution. Why dont you just load black bitmap?

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.r);  //example, 
                int[] pixels = new int[bm.getWidth()*bm.getHeight()];
                bm.getPixels(pixels, 0, bm.getWidth(),0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight()); //filling the array, this might throw some outofboundaryindex exception for the array, check again.
                int i = 0;
               while(i!=bm.getWidth()*bm.getHeight())
               {
                   if(pixels[i]==hexforblack)
                   {
                       swap it with hex of white
                   }
                   i++;
               }
```

Here you can find hex values of the colors

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp